# Catching current touch event on previously hidden view

Tags: android, android-layout

I have been struggling for quite a while with a problem related to catching current touch event in a view that becomes dynamically visible. 
I have been doing a lot of research and I cant seem to find an answer to my problem and I hope some one here can help or point me in the right direction.

I have tried various ways concerning touch listeners and events but without any luck.

The scenario is this: I have this overlay view which is hidden until the user long presses an icon. When the user long presses the Icon the view becomes visible and scales up to cover the screen. The functionality I am trying to achieve is that the view overlay stays open as long as the user is still pressing the screen. While the user is pressing the screen the user should be able to drag his/her finger around the screen to hover over other icons that are inside the overlay. Once the user releases or lifts the finger from the screen the view should scale down and hide once again.

The functionality described is something that some of you have probably come across when interacting with various apps. Thanks in advance for your time.